# How to apply transparency on pattern in pgf

Tags: tikz-pgf, transparency, pattern

I've created a shape with pgf and i would like to add an option for transparency (to a part of my shape). I change the opacity with `\pgfsetstrokeopacity` and `\pgfsetfillopacity`. It works except that the different lines are blending due to opacity:

[image: pattern blending in stroke]

I added a `pgftransparencygroup` but it does not help. To be sure I checked to remove the pattern and use a normal filling. It was still blending except if I was using the `knockout=true` option. But this does not change the result with the pattern.

Reduce version of the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgflibrary{patterns}

\pgfdeclareshape{opacityTest}
{

    \anchor{center}{\pgfpoint{0}{0}}

    \backgroundpath{
        \begin{pgftransparencygroup}[knockout=true]
        \pgfsetlinewidth{2pt}
        \pgfsetstrokeopacity{0.3}
        \pgfsetfillopacity{0.3}

        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0}{0}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1cm}{0}}
        \pgfusepath{stroke}

        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0}{0}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1cm}{0}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1cm}{1cm}}
        \pgfusepath{stroke}

        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0}{0}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1cm}{0}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1cm}{1cm}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0}{1cm}}
        \pgfclosepath
        %\pgfsetfillpattern{north west lines}{black}
        \pgfusepath{fill}

        \end{pgftransparencygroup}
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[opacityTest] at (0,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I did not find any help online about this problem with pgf, only with tikz.

Thanks in advance

Rmq: This code will still blend in overleaf. I mainly use pdflatex on Ubuntu 22.04 (pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the group transparency outside the group

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepgflibrary{patterns}
\pgfdeclareshape{opacityTest}
{
    \anchor{center}{\pgfpoint{0}{0}}
    \backgroundpath{
        \pgfsetlinewidth{2pt}
        \pgfsetstrokeopacity{0.3}
        \pgfsetfillopacity{0.3}
        \begin{pgftransparencygroup}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0}{0}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1cm}{0}}
        \pgfusepath{stroke}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0}{0}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1cm}{0}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1cm}{1cm}}
        \pgfusepath{stroke}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0}{0}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1cm}{0}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1cm}{1cm}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0}{1cm}}
        \pgfclosepath
        \pgfsetfillpattern{north west lines}{black}
        \pgfusepath{fill}
        \end{pgftransparencygroup}
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[opacityTest] at (0,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Square with diagonal gray lines]