# set transparent color for a pgfpicture

Tags: color, backgrounds, transparency, pgf-core

I have a simple document which inputs `picture.tex` file that includs data of a `pgfpicture`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\pagecolor{black} % set the page colour to black    
\begin{document}
\input{./picture.tex}
\end{document}
```

Data of a `pgfpicture` (here is `picture.tex`) is generated by `Octave` from its figure by running `print -dtikz "picture.tex"` command. For simplicity I removed its drawing and remained background only:

```
\begin{pgfpicture}
\color[rgb]{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}
\pgfpathrectanglecorners{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0pt}}{\pgfpoint{479pt}{359pt}}
\pgfusepath{fill}
\end{pgfpicture}
```

I want to set the background color of picture to be *transparent* and did a quick search; but did not found any thing, so as you can see I set it manually as `black` to be same as `pagecolor` of main ".tex" file. But in this way I have to change the background color every time I change the `pagecolor` and it needs remembering and also is a time consumer act. Is there a way to set the background color really transparent?

This a simple output from `Octave` which only draw a single point on a white background:

```
\begin{pgfpicture}
\color[rgb]{1.000000,1.000000,1.000000}
\pgfpathrectanglecorners{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0pt}}{\pgfpoint{479pt}{359pt}}
\pgfusepath{fill}
\begin{pgfscope}
\pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0pt}}{\pgfpoint{479pt}{359pt}}
\pgfusepath{fill}
\pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0pt}}{\pgfpoint{479pt}{359pt}}
\pgfusepath{clip}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{434.158691pt}{332.015137pt}}
\pgflineto{\pgfpoint{434.158691pt}{38.778320pt}}
\pgflineto{\pgfpoint{62.365234pt}{38.778320pt}}
\pgfpathclose
\pgfusepath{fill,stroke}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{62.365234pt}{332.015137pt}}
\pgflineto{\pgfpoint{434.158691pt}{332.015137pt}}
\pgflineto{\pgfpoint{62.365234pt}{38.778320pt}}
\pgfpathclose
\pgfusepath{fill,stroke}
\color[rgb]{0.150000,0.150000,0.150000}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.500000pt}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{62.365234pt}{42.499023pt}}
\pgflineto{\pgfpoint{62.365234pt}{38.778320pt}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{62.365234pt}{328.293945pt}}
\pgflineto{\pgfpoint{62.365234pt}{332.015137pt}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{155.313477pt}{42.499023pt}}
\pgflineto{\pgfpoint{155.313477pt}{38.778320pt}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{155.313477pt}{328.293945pt}}
\pgflineto{\pgfpoint{155.313477pt}{332.015137pt}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{248.261719pt}{42.499023pt}}
\pgflineto{\pgfpoint{248.261719pt}{38.778320pt}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{248.261719pt}{328.293945pt}}
\pgflineto{\pgfpoint{248.261719pt}{332.015137pt}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{341.209961pt}{42.499023pt}}
\pgflineto{\pgfpoint{341.209961pt}{38.778320pt}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{341.209961pt}{328.293945pt}}
\pgflineto{\pgfpoint{341.209961pt}{332.015137pt}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{434.158691pt}{42.499023pt}}
\pgflineto{\pgfpoint{434.158691pt}{38.778320pt}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{434.158691pt}{328.293945pt}}
\pgflineto{\pgfpoint{434.158691pt}{332.015137pt}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
{
\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{62.365234pt}{31.271973pt}}
\pgfnode{rectangle}{north}{\fontsize{10}{0}\selectfont\textcolor[rgb]{0.15,0.15,0.15}{{0.9}}}{}{\pgfusepath{discard}}
}
{
\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{155.313477pt}{31.271973pt}}
\pgfnode{rectangle}{north}{\fontsize{10}{0}\selectfont\textcolor[rgb]{0.15,0.15,0.15}{{0.95}}}{}{\pgfusepath{discard}}
}
{
\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{248.261719pt}{31.271973pt}}
\pgfnode{rectangle}{north}{\fontsize{10}{0}\selectfont\textcolor[rgb]{0.15,0.15,0.15}{{1}}}{}{\pgfusepath{discard}}
}
{
\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{341.209961pt}{31.271973pt}}
\pgfnode{rectangle}{north}{\fontsize{10}{0}\selectfont\textcolor[rgb]{0.15,0.15,0.15}{{1.05}}}{}{\pgfusepath{discard}}
}
{
\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{434.158691pt}{31.271973pt}}
\pgfnode{rectangle}{north}{\fontsize{10}{0}\selectfont\textcolor[rgb]{0.15,0.15,0.15}{{1.1}}}{}{\pgfusepath{discard}}
}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{66.081055pt}{38.778320pt}}
\pgflineto{\pgfpoint{62.365234pt}{38.778320pt}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{430.442871pt}{38.778320pt}}
\pgflineto{\pgfpoint{434.158691pt}{38.778320pt}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{66.081055pt}{112.087402pt}}
\pgflineto{\pgfpoint{62.365234pt}{112.087402pt}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{430.442871pt}{112.087402pt}}
\pgflineto{\pgfpoint{434.158691pt}{112.087402pt}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{66.081055pt}{185.396484pt}}
\pgflineto{\pgfpoint{62.365234pt}{185.396484pt}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{430.442871pt}{185.396484pt}}
\pgflineto{\pgfpoint{434.158691pt}{185.396484pt}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{66.081055pt}{258.705566pt}}
\pgflineto{\pgfpoint{62.365234pt}{258.705566pt}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{430.442871pt}{258.705566pt}}
\pgflineto{\pgfpoint{434.158691pt}{258.705566pt}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{66.081055pt}{332.015137pt}}
\pgflineto{\pgfpoint{62.365234pt}{332.015137pt}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{430.442871pt}{332.015137pt}}
\pgflineto{\pgfpoint{434.158691pt}{332.015137pt}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
{
\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{57.368164pt}{38.778320pt}}
\pgfnode{rectangle}{east}{\fontsize{10}{0}\selectfont\textcolor[rgb]{0.15,0.15,0.15}{{0.9}}}{}{\pgfusepath{discard}}
}
{
\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{57.368164pt}{112.087402pt}}
\pgfnode{rectangle}{east}{\fontsize{10}{0}\selectfont\textcolor[rgb]{0.15,0.15,0.15}{{0.95}}}{}{\pgfusepath{discard}}
}
{
\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{57.368164pt}{185.396484pt}}
\pgfnode{rectangle}{east}{\fontsize{10}{0}\selectfont\textcolor[rgb]{0.15,0.15,0.15}{{1}}}{}{\pgfusepath{discard}}
}
{
\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{57.368164pt}{258.705566pt}}
\pgfnode{rectangle}{east}{\fontsize{10}{0}\selectfont\textcolor[rgb]{0.15,0.15,0.15}{{1.05}}}{}{\pgfusepath{discard}}
}
{
\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{57.368164pt}{332.015137pt}}
\pgfnode{rectangle}{east}{\fontsize{10}{0}\selectfont\textcolor[rgb]{0.15,0.15,0.15}{{1.1}}}{}{\pgfusepath{discard}}
}
\pgfsetrectcap
\pgfsetdash{{16pt}{0pt}}{0pt}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{434.158691pt}{38.778320pt}}
\pgflineto{\pgfpoint{62.365234pt}{38.778320pt}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{434.158691pt}{332.015137pt}}
\pgflineto{\pgfpoint{62.365234pt}{332.015137pt}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{62.365234pt}{332.015137pt}}
\pgflineto{\pgfpoint{62.365234pt}{38.778320pt}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{434.158691pt}{332.015137pt}}
\pgflineto{\pgfpoint{434.158691pt}{38.778320pt}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.01pt}
\color[rgb]{0.000000,0.447000,0.741000}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{247.761719pt}{184.530273pt}}
\pgflineto{\pgfpoint{248.761719pt}{184.530273pt}}
\pgflineto{\pgfpoint{249.261719pt}{185.396484pt}}
\pgfpathclose
\pgfusepath{fill,stroke}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{247.261719pt}{185.396484pt}}
\pgflineto{\pgfpoint{247.761719pt}{184.530273pt}}
\pgflineto{\pgfpoint{249.261719pt}{185.396484pt}}
\pgfpathclose
\pgfusepath{fill,stroke}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{247.761719pt}{186.262695pt}}
\pgflineto{\pgfpoint{247.261719pt}{185.396484pt}}
\pgflineto{\pgfpoint{249.261719pt}{185.396484pt}}
\pgfpathclose
\pgfusepath{fill,stroke}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{248.761719pt}{186.262695pt}}
\pgflineto{\pgfpoint{247.761719pt}{186.262695pt}}
\pgflineto{\pgfpoint{249.261719pt}{185.396484pt}}
\pgfpathclose
\pgfusepath{fill,stroke}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{249.261719pt}{185.396484pt}}
\pgflineto{\pgfpoint{248.761719pt}{186.262695pt}}
\pgflineto{\pgfpoint{249.261719pt}{185.396484pt}}
\pgfpathclose
\pgfusepath{fill,stroke}
\end{pgfscope}
\end{pgfpicture}
```

For a real drawing, the output file contains more than 3000 lines.

Comment: Maybe related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/667086

Comment: Conside providing a complete MWE, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228.

Comment: you can use `\pgfsetfillopacity{0}` but you would have to scope it, so that it doesn't affect the rest of your picture. (But I don't understand why you fill the background at all if you don't want it).

Comment: This feels like something you want to control via Octave. Can't you let it export your pictures *without* the background rectangle? How are you controlling the color inside Octave?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I searched a lot for exporting drawing without its background; but unfortunately did not found any thing.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It is rational to remove the background instead of filling it; but I did not know which part is about background and which part is about drawing (function). I only see a single `\begin{pgfscope}` there.

Comment: @hasanghaforian Let's start with another question: Why is your background black? Do you plan to print this somewhere? The generated code fills more than one rectangle and also uses `\pgflineto` which is very old. There's a lot going on in your diagram …

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel The background is black because I prefer the dark mode. Also Octave uses old `\pgflineto` and it seems I cannot avoid it.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Can I replace `\pgflineto`s, by find/replace, with another newer command to reduce the size of output?